# Извлечение первой строки DataFrame по совпадению значения столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Допустим, есть DataFrame:

```
|           |name|  adress | age |
|:----------|:--:|:-------:|:---:|
|   **0**   |Jack|adress111| 25  |
|   **1**   |John|adress123| 52  |
|   **2**   |Jack|adress349| 25  |
|   **3**   |Jack|adress782| 25  |
|   **4**   |Nick|adress821| 41  |
|   **5**   |John|adress821| 52  |
|    ---    | ---|   ---   |---  |
|**2125369**|Jack|adress199| 25  |
```

В столбце name есть 3 (в оригинале их 800) уникальных значений и точно так же 3 уникальных значения в столбце `age`.

Как мне получить словарь `{name:age}` (или новый DataFrame в общем любую структуру), за минимально короткое время?

Думал как-то извлекать строку при первом совпадении, но нашел только способ перебора всего массива, но значений много и это происходит очень долго.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
In [21]: df[["name", "age"]].drop_duplicates()
Out[21]:
   name  age
0  Jack   25
1  John   52
4  Nick   41
```

в виде словаря:

```
In [22]: df[["name", "age"]].drop_duplicates().to_dict("records")
Out[22]:
[{'name': 'Jack', 'age': 25},
 {'name': 'John', 'age': 52},
 {'name': 'Nick', 'age': 41}]
```

---

если вам нужно получить все столбцы, но удалить строки с повторяющимися `name` и `age`:

```
In [23]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=["name", "age"])
Out[23]:
   name     adress  age
0  Jack  adress111   25
1  John  adress123   52
4  Nick  adress821   41
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно! Благодарю за точную инструкцию с несколькими вариантами!